# Xamarin NSDraggingDestination

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am new to XCode and Xamarin.Mac and would like to create a application which can accept a file drop.

Basically i want the user to drag and drop a file on my application.

I have found some tutorials on this but cant get it done in Xamarin.

I tryed to created a new View called "DropImageView" and now i want to implement 
NSDraggingSource, NSDraggingDestination and NSPasteboardItemDataProvider

Since these classes are no interfaces i am asking how can my view implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is dragging from outside your app into your app, you can register for the type of files that your custom  "drop target" view (or window) allows and then override the methods like `DraggingEntered`, `DraggingExited`, etc...

#### Example:

```
public partial class MyDragTargetView : NSView
{
    public MyDragTargetView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) { }

    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();
        RegisterForDraggedTypes(new string[] { NSPasteboard.NSFilenamesType });
    }

    public override NSDragOperation DraggingEntered(NSDraggingInfo sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User is dragging file(s) in our view");
        // we can look at the sender.DraggingPasteboard to determine condition to return... 
        return NSDragOperation.Copy;
    }

    public override void DraggingEnded(NSDraggingInfo sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User has dragged file(s) in our view, lets do something with them");
        var dragItems = NSString.FromData(sender.DraggingPasteboard.GetDataForType(NSPasteboard.NSFilenamesType), NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
        Console.WriteLine("NSFilenamesType Data: " + dragItems);
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
User is dragging file(s) in our view
User has dragged file(s) in our view, lets do something with them
NSFilenamesType Data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>/Users/sushi/Desktop/DFeedback_FeedBack.png</string>
    <string>/Users/sushi/Desktop/DFeedback_BugFeedBack.png</string>
</array>
</plist>
```